# Firebase snapshot listeners with authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

My apologies if this question has been asked before.

I have searched through stackoverflow, but have not found an answer to a problem I'm coming up with quite often. I'm working on a few projects which I'm developing using Firebase.

I often have a data structure something like this:

```
collection A:
  - userID
  - attribute1
  - attribute2
(and so on)
```

On the client I then declare some snapshot listeners. My question is about where I should declare my snapshot listeners.

If my security rules allow collection A to be read and written (including create, update and delete) if the `userID` field of the document is the same as the id of the logged in user how should I declare my snapshot listeners?

Should I do the following?

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{
  firebase.firestore().collection('collectionA').where('userID', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).onSnapshot((snapshot)=>{
  // DO STUFF HERE
}
)
})
```

or just

```
firebase.firestore().collection('collectionA').where('userID', '==', firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).onSnapshot((snapshot)=>{
  // DO STUFF HERE
})
```

or none of the above?

Comment: In your first variant, the snapshot listener is only used if the status of the user changes. For example, when the user logs out. That doesn't make much sense to me since the user no longer has a uid and therefore can no longer access attributes.
I would therefore generally prefer the second variant because you want the user to be able to access their attributes all the time and not only when their status is changing?! . Nonetheless, if you incorporate an unsubscribe function, the first version will probably be your method of choice.

Comment: If I use the second variant will the snapshot automatically rerun when the user logs in/out.

Comment: No. For those kind of things you should go with the first method. As @ked wrote...in most cases you will be fine with the second method. If you want any more specific information you have to provide more Information about the context you plan using this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are valid ways of adding snapshotlisteners, but if you have a logged in user with [persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence) as **local** or **session**, then there is no need to add authchangeState listener everytime; you can directly use second method

Comment: If I use the second method do I need to unsubscribe snapshot listeners and if so how do I do this?